# can't convert byte literal from request to unicode in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am sending a request to an API (from Indeed.com) and in the response.content I have a byte literal with characters like this (it is a € symbol)

```
30 April (30\xe2\x82\xac)
```

The problem is, that I am failing to convert it to a proper string

If I do a

```
response.text
--> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character
```

same issue for

```
  response.content.decode('utf8')
```

but if i run some manual test

```
sb = b"\'\xe2\x82\xac"
sb.decode('utf8')
print(sb.decode('utf8'))
```

it outputs the € symbol.

Also I have set the request header of the get request to

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
```

Any ideas what is the issue with the encoding here, and how to get the data into a string?
Also, if I run the same request postman those characters are displayed correct.

EDIT: 
I think I found the issue, inside of my venv for the project the encoding is failing, outside it works. 
So I guess some package is messing this up, but no idea which one? Because requests version (2.21.0) is the same in and outside the venv

Comment: Post your code. I think the issue is that you're getting the encoded values as a string instead of bytes.

Comment: Try  response.content.decode('utf-8')

Comment: @DroidX86 standard request.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
the headers is the one I posted plus an Authorization
I think so this is the issue that the encoded values are strings. Is this even possible to fix?

Comment: Check the `type` and encoding of `response.content` if it's `str` then probably that's the isse

Comment: `response.content` is of type `<class 'bytes'>` so it is a byte literal.

Comment: And the encoding?

Comment: how can I check the encoding of a byte literal? not sure how to find out

Answer (score 0):

After several tests the issue was that the python installation for the project had a wrong encoding setting.

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
```

this fixes the issue